# Any Other way to print $0 without using print in awk?

Tags: awk

I am solving this question http://www.spoj.com/problems/NEXTODD/

In this question You have to solve it in minimum number of bytes.

My code :- `{print$1%2?$1+2:$1+1}` which is 21 bytes.

Best solution is in 10 bytes.

Is there any other way to print $0 without using print or printf statement which can help me to reduce my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the pattern/action language of AWK, there is an implicit action of printing of $0 when the pattern evaluates to true, but there is no explicit action described. Regarding your challenge, see this example (13 characters):

```
{$0+=$0%2+1}1
```

Hat tip to 'some guy', who was quicker on the draw to post the code than me.

Comment: thanks for your code.. great code..really helpfull trick..:) will you please guide me some sites where I can help some tips for awk :)

Comment: Thank you @Guru, some-guy! avinashse, check out the resources at: http://awk.info/ . In brief, read the original Awk book, the GNU Awk manual, and the O'reilly AWK books. My $0.02.

Comment: @taltman please check my solution too.. and guide me in that solution.

Answer (score 3):

Shorter by two characters:

`'{$0%2?$0+=2:$0+=1}1'`

`1` here instead of `{print $0}`. `1` is pattern, that matches any record. `{print $0}` is default action.

**Edited.** Even better ( -6 characters ):

`{$0+=$0%2?2:1}1`

Comment: will you please guide me some sites where I can have these basic tips for awk.. :)

Comment: please check my solution too.. and guide me in that solution.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is the condition since it can never be non-zero and so will always invoke the default action of printing the current record:

```
awk '$0+=$0%2+1'
```

Comment: thanks for the solution and please check my solution too.. and guide me in that solution.

Comment: Please explain why the solution you posted is the correct answer to your question rather than this solution or one of the others.

Comment: no I am not saying is correct answer for the question I have posted, yours is the shortest code but still in the link the best solution is 10 chars n I was thinking and did that but its longer, so i asked for help if this can be golfed further.

Answer (score 0):

I also researched a trick for this.. can this be golfed ?

```
{$0=or($0+1,1)}1
```

Comment: As requested, some feedback: "or" is gawk-specific and that solution is 16 chars which is 6 chars longer than the one I posted so it wouldn't be a good choice. On a side note - I had no idea stackoverflow would let you post a solution to your own question and then let you select that solution as the correct answer, feels wrong to me....

Comment: I know thats 6 character, is there any way to golf that or.

Comment: No, there isn't, at least not enough to get it into the ballpark. `'$0=or($0+1,1)'` but then it's still GNU-awk specific and longer than other solutions.